# how to have root partition LVM for RHEL 5.8 64 bit on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm, amazon-ec2

I have to create a RHEL 5.8 Amazon Machine Image (AMI) in which the root partition should be a logical volume. I know how to create a data partition as a logical volume but am not able to find how to create the root partition as a LVM.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish by doing this? Part of the point of EC2 is that you shouldn't need to bother.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the same as a data partition. Just the `/boot` partition can't live on LVM. At least in Fedora, the installer guides you through all steps here.